# Error Installing Firebase Database

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods

I'm working in a iOS project (I'm new to programming in `XCode`). I tried to install **pod 'Firebase/Database'** but gives me an error (see next image): [image: error Firebase]

(35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to www.gstatic.com:-36

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Next time you want to take a snapshot of your screen , use cmd+shift+3, also give the code for your pod File.

Comment: Follow the link on how to integrate your firebase http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38262378/ios-firebase-push-notification-project/38264248#38264248

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37799702/curl-intermittent-error-35-unknown-ssl-protocol-error-in-connection